# How to console the PHP echo in my javascript?

Tags: php

I can not get the PHP echo in my Ajax.

This is my `test01.html` code:

In my HTML code, I quote the jQuery, and I bind the event in my "sub01" button, I use Ajax provide the POST request:

```js
$(".sub01").bind("click", function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "cms/test01.php?action=test01",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      "var_01": "var_01_value",
      "var_02": "var_02_value",
    },
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response) // there I want to console the response from PHP.
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <form>
    <input type="text" value="var_01">
    <input type="text" value="var_02">
    <input id="sub01" type="submit" value="click me!">
  </form>
</div>
```

And this is my PHP `test01.php` code:

in my PHP code I want to echo the `$_POST`, then I want the AJAX code get the response.

```
<?php
echo $_POST;
```

I want the code

```
success: function(response) {
  console.log(response) // there I want to console the response from PHP.
}
```

shows the PHP echo, but there console nothing.

Comment: If you press F12 in your browser and go to network analysis -> run your ajax request -> what does your request send as response?

Comment: You can't `echo` `$_POST` as `$_POST` is an array, thus this will result in a notice. Go with `var_dump($_POST)`

Comment: Btw `echo $_POST` doesnt make sense, it will just print `Array`. You´d have to use `$_POST['var_01']` or var_02

Comment: you need to add in form   method=post

Comment: @vikas _“you need to add in form method=post”_ - no they don’t, because that form itself does not get submitted. The `$.ajax` call is what sends the data to the server, and in there it is specified that the request method is to be POST.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Problem 1

**You never call your JS function**

> ```
> $(".sub01").bind
> ```

You are binding to the click event of elements with the **class** sub01.

> ```
> <input id="sub01" type="submit" value="click me!">
> ```

Your button doesn't have that class!

Aside: `bind` is deprecated in favour of `on`.

```
$("#sub01).on("click" ....
```

## Problem 2

**You aren't letting the JS run**

Since you are (trying) to run the JS when a **submit** button is clicked, the form is submitting.

The browser is leaving the page before the Ajax response comes back and triggers the success function.

You need to prevent the default behavior of the submit button.

```
$("#sub01").on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // etc
});
```

## Problem 3

**You aren't parsing the response correctly**

You said `dataType: "json",` which means "Tell the server I only `Accept` JSON and ignore the `Content-Type` and parse the response as JSON regardless".

Since the server is not responding with JSON, the attempt to parse the response fails and it errors.

### Option 1

**Remove `dataType: "json"`.**

This will process the response as invalid HTML (because PHP sends `Content-Type: text/html` by default).

Then you will echo the response (which is *Array* … probably not the response you want PHP to send though).

### Option 2

**Change the PHP so it responds with JSON**

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    echo json_encode($_POST, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: Add a hint about browser's dev tools to see the response, and this should be full answer.

Comment: @s-n-2 — I've updated the answer with some notes on the other problems I spotted when I went looking past the obvious error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to output a json.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($_POST);
```